# Default signature provider is not working from DocuSign SDK

Tags: docusignapi

After some research in different customers that we have we have notice something strange.

When an account has not enabled any other signature type than default and we call the API call ‘GetAccountInformationAsync' the available signature provider is ‘universalsignaturepen_default’.

Then when we call the API call ‘CreateEnvelopeAsync’ and in the SignatureProviderName field of RecipientSignatureProviders we set the ‘universalsignaturepen_default’ value we get the error

> {"errorCode":"SIGNATURE_PROVIDER_INVALID_FOR_NONSBS","message":"Signature
> providers are not valid for this recipient. Standards Based Signatures
> must be enabled for the sending account. Envelope is not configured
> for support of recipient signing providers"}

This happens only when the Account has not enabled any other signature type.

In any other case (ex: the Account has more than 1 available signature provider), this works fine.

Please enlighten us why this is happening cause is not normal.

Comment: Please accept (check) the best answer to each question. ***Thank you!!***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. As the error message says, you can only select a `signature provider` if the account is set to use standards based signatures (SBS).

To put it another way, if the account only has the universalsignaturepen_default pen type, then **do not** specify the signature provider.

Comment: Can I change the default signature type from the account settings if I have more than one signature providers ? Now the first option is ADACOM-Dev (docusign portal dropdown) and every time I need to change it to Electronic for every signer.

Comment: Please ask as a new question. StackOverflow is not a forum. Thank you